# select multiple tables and generate a new table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

perhaps this question has already been asked, but i didn't found a answer with the phrases i searched.

I have got a mariadb (mysql) database with the following tables:

```
+--------------------------------+                                           
| Tables_in_systemvariablen      |
+--------------------------------+
| items                          |
| lm_energy_l0_0041              |
| lm_energy_l1_0043              |
| lm_energy_l2_0048              |
| lm_energy_l3_0042              |
| lm_energy_p0_0050              |
| lm_energy_p1_0051              |
| lm_energy_p2_0052              |
| lm_energy_p3_0053              |
| lm_energy_pch_0040             |
```

where items is a list of all the entries in the database:

```
+--------+---------------------------+
| ItemId | itemname                  |
+--------+---------------------------+
|      1 | Sun_Azimuth               |
|      2 | Sun_Elevation             |
|      3 | wkw_gen_p0                |
|      4 | wkw_gen_p1                |
|      5 | wkw_gen_p2                |
|      6 | wkw_gen_p3                |
|      7 | wkw_gen_q0                |
|      8 | wkw_gen_q1                |
|      9 | wkw_gen_q2                |
```

And each item has in it the values stored as they occur.

```
+-------------------------+-------+
| time                    | value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| 2017-08-24 02:33:39.531 |   4.2 |
| 2017-08-24 02:34:05.756 |   4.1 |
| 2017-08-24 02:59:07.434 |   4.2 |
| 2017-08-24 02:59:23.811 |   4.1 |
| 2017-08-24 03:02:05.940 |   4.2 |
| 2017-08-24 03:42:47.482 |   4.3 |
| 2017-08-24 03:44:20.967 |   4.2 |
| 2017-08-24 03:44:58.678 |   4.3 |
| 2017-08-24 03:50:31.715 |   4.2 |
| 2017-08-24 03:50:38.273 |   4.3 |
```

Now i want to generate an output file where all items are listed after the time of occurrence. I found in several different answers here commands, which i combined to this one, which also works fine.

```
select a.time, 'lm_energy_p0_0050' , a.value as table_type from lm_energy_p0_0050 a UNION select b.time, 'lm_energy_p1_0051', b.value as table_type from lm_energy_p1_0051 b where time> '2017.08.24 00:00:00.000'  and time<'2017.08.24 23:59:59.999' order by time;
```

The output looks like this (it is only a coincidence that the two items have the same value)

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+------------+
| time                    | lm_energy_p0_0050 | table_type |
+-------------------------+-------------------+------------+
| 2017-08-24 09:17:52.898 | lm_energy_p0_0050 |       1890 |
| 2017-08-24 09:17:52.901 | lm_energy_p1_0051 |       1890 |
| 2017-08-24 09:17:56.920 | lm_energy_p1_0051 |       1878 |
| 2017-08-24 09:17:58.310 | lm_energy_p0_0050 |       1874 |
| 2017-08-24 09:17:58.314 | lm_energy_p1_0051 |       1874 |
| 2017-08-24 09:17:59.631 | lm_energy_p0_0050 |       1871 |
| 2017-08-24 09:17:59.633 | lm_energy_p1_0051 |       1871 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:00.954 | lm_energy_p1_0051 |       1858 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:00.954 | lm_energy_p0_0050 |       1862 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:02.341 | lm_energy_p1_0051 |       1861 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:02.343 | lm_energy_p0_0050 |       1861 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:03.667 | lm_energy_p0_0050 |       1856 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:03.668 | lm_energy_p1_0051 |       1856 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:04.986 | lm_energy_p0_0050 |       1853 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:06.377 | lm_energy_p0_0050 |       1852 |
| 2017-08-24 09:18:06.380 | lm_energy_p1_0051 |       1852 |
```

Now i want to generate a table for all itemnames and put it into a file. The export into a file works also fine with extending the command with:

```
into outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/output.txt' fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\n';
```

But with my current command i would have to type every item separately. How do i have to modify my command so all tables are included but the table 'items' not?

Comment: Do all your tables follow the pattern lm_energy_p%?  How many are there?

Comment: No, they are absolutley random. e.g. Item 1 is Sun_Azimuth, which is in the main table Sun_Azimuth_0001. The main table is ordered in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

As your individual SELECT statements produce a value hard-coded as the table name you should use UNION ALL rather than UNION.

If there are too many tables to UNION then MariaDB/MySQL will give error messages.

Writing SQL to write SQL is an approach I would consider (known as meta-programming)

- Write a query against INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to generate the SELECT statement ending in a UNION ALL clause
- Use the OUTFILE clause to output the SQL Statements to a file with a SQL extension
- Use bash or PowerShell (which ever is appropriate) to cut the trailing UNION ALL statement from the file and pipe the results into a new SQL file.
- Execute your new SQL file as the `mysql -u username -p database_name < your_file.sql`

If there are too many tables for a UNION approach then use a similar approach to summarise data up into a single table only this time generating `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM...WHERE` statements.  The caveat with this latter approach is that the recency and refresh period of your data may make this impractical in fulfilling your user requirements.